# Which WebGL api's invalidate uniform values?

Tags: webgl

Suppose we have the following code:

```js
gl.useProgram(p1);
gl.uniform1i(p1_u, 5);
gl.drawArrays(...);

gl.useProgram(p2);
g.uniform1i(p2_u, 100);

// on another loop of the application
// i will   need to use p1 again
gl.useProgram(p1);
gl.uniform1i(p1_u, 5);           // <<------- A
```

`p1` & `p2` are `WebGLProgram`s and `p1_u`, `p2_u` are `WebGLUniformLocation`s.
Is it ok to to skip updating uniforms, if their values is not changed?
even after switching GLPrograms?

Or put in other words:
**Which WebGL api's invalidate uniform values, and makes it necessary to re-submit them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which WebGL api's invalidate uniform values, and makes it necessary to re-submit them?

None: All WebGL state stays exactly as you set it. There is no WebGL API that changes state indirectly except (deleteXXX)

Note that Uniform values are program state. In other words they are unique to each shader program.

Example:

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vsrc = `
attribute vec4 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  gl_PointSize = 40.0;
}
`;

const fsrc = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

const vs = createAndCompileShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsrc);
const fs = createAndCompileShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsrc);

const redPrg = linkProgramAndSetColor(gl, vs, fs, [1, 0, 0, 1]);
const bluePrg = linkProgramAndSetColor(gl, vs, fs, [0, 0, 1, 1]);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001; // convert to seconds;
  
  gl.useProgram(redPrg);
  gl.vertexAttrib2f(0, Math.cos(time), Math.sin(time));
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

  gl.useProgram(bluePrg);
  gl.vertexAttrib2f(0, Math.sin(time), Math.cos(time));
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function createAndCompileShader(gl, type, src) {
  const s = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(s, src);
  gl.compileShader(s);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(s, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(s));
  }
  return s;
}

function linkProgramAndSetColor(gl, vs, fs, color) {
  const p = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(p, vs);
  gl.attachShader(p, fs);
  gl.bindAttribLocation(p, 0, 'position');  // force position to location 0
  gl.linkProgram(p);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(p, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    throw new Error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(p));
  }
  gl.useProgram(p);
  gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(p, 'color'), color);
  return p;
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```